# user entry as part of query to SQLite with results back to screen

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to Android App development and was hoping if someone could help me with the sqlite query to search an item.

I want to take a string from the Edittext box and then use that string to search my sqlite database to display the entries back on the android screen. How can I do this?

For example if I wanted to find-
`select * from table_name where name= str1;` (here str1 is the string from edittext box).

How do I write the java code for this so that it displays all the information regarding str1 from the database to the android screen?

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

:-) The general way to go about it is to use something called `Cursor`. In the following code, `db` is the database.

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ table_name + ";");
```

You'll have to modify it to use your query instead. The next step is to get the values from the `Cursor`. `textview1` and so on are TextView's in your UI. I'll assume you know how to do this, but if you need help with this please let me know. `nameOfColumn` is the name of the columns in your database (I think that's `name` in your case)

```
if(cur.moveToFirst()) {
    if(cur != null){
        //Display the text in TextView's
        textview1.setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("nameOfColumn"));
        textview2.setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("nameOfColumn2"));
    }
 }
```

Hope this helps! :-)